# Javascript: How to concatenate templates after BD querys with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this code:

```
$("#addField1").on('click',function(){
        var tipo_proveedor_id = $("[name=tipo_proveedores_id]").val();
        var proveedor_id = $("[name=proveedores_id]").val();
        if(tipo_proveedor_id.length && proveedor_id.length ){
             var target = document.getElementById("proveedoresDiv");
             var template = '';
            $.get('/tipo-proveedor/'+tipo_proveedor_id+'', function(response){
                var data = response.response;
                alert(data[0].tipo)
                template += '<b>Tipo de proveedor:<br/><input class="form-control m-t-sm" type="text" name="tipo_proveedores_id[]" value="'+data[0].tipo+'readonly><br/>'
            });
            $.get('/proveedor/'+proveedor_id+'', function(response){
                var data = response.response;
                alert(data[0].nombre_compania_p)
                template += 'Proveedor:<br/><input class="form-control m-t-sm" type="text" name="proveedores_id[]" value="'+data[0].nombre_compania_p+'" readonly>'     
            });
            alert(template)
            target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + template;
    }
```

i have a `template` variable that concatenates bd results of an ajax call, the calls works fine but idk why it doesn't concatenates the results, i show the content of `template` with `alert()` but it shows a null string, what's wrong with this? help pls

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax calls are asychronous. The concatenation doesn't occur until there is a response from the server. However the code outside of the ajax functions will run immediately. The alert happens before the concatenation. Try this instead

```
$("#addField1").on('click',function(){
    var tipo_proveedor_id = $("[name=tipo_proveedores_id]").val();
    var proveedor_id = $("[name=proveedores_id]").val();
    if(tipo_proveedor_id.length && proveedor_id.length ){
         var target = document.getElementById("proveedoresDiv");
         var template = '';
        $.get('/tipo-proveedor/'+tipo_proveedor_id+'', function(response){
            var data = response.response;
            alert(data[0].tipo)
            template += '<b>Tipo de proveedor:<br/><input class="form-control m-t-sm" type="text" name="tipo_proveedores_id[]" value="'+data[0].tipo+'readonly><br/>'
            alert(template)
            target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + template;            

        });
        $.get('/proveedor/'+proveedor_id+'', function(response){
            var data = response.response;
            alert(data[0].nombre_compania_p)
            template += 'Proveedor:<br/><input class="form-control m-t-sm" type="text" name="proveedores_id[]" value="'+data[0].nombre_compania_p+'" readonly>'     
            alert(template)
            target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + template;           
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it won't work because, the **get** function is asynchronous, witch means, that when you called:

```
alert(template)
target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + template;
```

after the 2 **get** functions, those two lines will execute before getting the results of the Ajax calls. What you need to do, is to force an execution order by putting your code in the **get** success function like this (I suppose your code works fine):

```
$("#addField1").on('click',function(){
        var tipo_proveedor_id = $("[name=tipo_proveedores_id]").val();
        var proveedor_id = $("[name=proveedores_id]").val();
        if(tipo_proveedor_id.length && proveedor_id.length ){
             var target = document.getElementById("proveedoresDiv");
             var template = '';
            $.get('/tipo-proveedor/'+tipo_proveedor_id+'', function(response){
                var data = response.response;
                alert(data[0].tipo)
                template += '<b>Tipo de proveedor:<br/><input class="form-control m-t-sm" type="text" name="tipo_proveedores_id[]" value="'+data[0].tipo+'readonly><br/>';

                // launch second Ajax
                $.get('/proveedor/'+proveedor_id+'', function(response){
                    var data = response.response;
                    alert(data[0].nombre_compania_p)
                    template += 'Proveedor:<br/><input class="form-control m-t-sm" type="text" name="proveedores_id[]" value="'+data[0].nombre_compania_p+'" readonly>';

                    alert(template)
                    target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + template;
                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that, the first template concatenates fine, but the second doesn't concatenate, im geting mad rly

Comment: in the second get call, are you sure you are receiving something? (it hard for me to test without being able to do the calls to your sites)

Comment: Any news about this?